# objective-c arm64に設定を変更してビルドを行うとエラーになる。

Tags: ios, objective-c

### 状況

現在、バーコードを読み込んで、kintone内のデータを更新するプログラムがあります。
iOS11上でアプリが稼働しなくなったため、Architecturesがarmv7の32ビットアプリであったこともあり、Architecturesをarm64に変更しビルドを行ったところ、下記のエラーが発生してしまいました。このエラーの原因を教えていただけますでしょうか。
Architecturesをarmv7に戻すと正常にビルドできるため、フレームワーク自体の設定は正しくできていると思います。

### エラー内容

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /(パス省略)/Framework/kintone.framework/kintone, missing required architecture arm64 in file /(パス省略)/Framework/kintone.framework/kintone (3 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_KintoneSite", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_KintoneQuery", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_KintoneField", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_KintoneRecord", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CBOperationQueue", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CBCredential", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

### 環境

- 対象機種

  - iOS11のiPad mini 4
- 開発言語

  - Objective-C
- 開発環境

  - MAC Xcode9
- 外部参照プログラム

  - [ZXingObjC](https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC)
  - [kintone SDK(β) for iOS](https://developer.cybozu.io/hc/ja/articles/202640770-kintone-API-SDK-%CE%B2-for-iOS)

Answer (score 0):

> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

と書いてある通り、kintone.frameworkにはarm64のオブジェクトファイルが含まれていません。

アップデートされるのを待つか、ソースコードは公開されているようですので、ご自身でフレームワークをビルドしなおせば解決すると思います。